# Loop and merge XML files in a folder to one HTML file using Groovy script?

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, soapui

I am using ReadyAPI and trying to fetch my reports generation, so I'm at the point where all the xml files for each test case are generated, and I need to merge them.

So basically I only have a path where the files are, let's say "C:\Path", where XML files lie.

I have found parsers for single files, and ways to append some information of one XML file into another XML file, but I have not found the way to loop through all XML files and dump their content into a new file...

Any help or indication could be much appreciated...

Jackson.

Comment: `new File('C:/Path').eachFile{file-> ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working example of this answer [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_35_stack_overflow_51103455).

Let's assume that we have XML files of this form:

```
<composer>
  <name>Wolfgang Mozart</name>
  <born>1756</born>
</composer>
```

Then, we could build a list of parsed XML documents from each `.xml` file in the current directory (or whichever you need):

```
def composers = []

new File(".").eachFile { def file ->
    if (file.name ==~ /.*\.xml/) {
        composers << new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
    }
}
```

Then, we could use a `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to create a unified XML document. Note this mixes markup with the `composers` list built above:

```
def xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    root {
        composers.each { c ->
            mkp.yield c
        }
    }
}.toString()
```

That is, the document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <composer>
    <name>Wolfgang Mozart</name>
    <born>1756</born>
  </composer>
  <composer>
    <name>JS Bach</name>
    <born>1685</born>
  </composer>
...
</root>
```

Altering the solution for your local goals should be straight-forward.